# How to recreate a table Column based on dropdown selection

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying a table dynamically using Angular JS .
This is workig fine

Initially when the Page is loaded , the fourth  column (Domains)  is being displayed , based on Banking Values.

In case we change the drop down to Finance , how to display finance values under the Fourth column ?

Do we need to recreate the table ?

My Code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in collectioninfo[0]">
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)>=0">
               <select ng-change="getchange(selectItem)" ng-model="selectItem" ng-init="selectItem = key">
                  <option>{{key}}</option>
                  <option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val[0]" value="{{k}}">{{k}}</option>
               </select>
            </span>
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)<0">
            {{ key }}
            </span>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in collectioninfo">
         <td ng-repeat="(key2, val2) in row">
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)>=0">
            {{ getFirstKeyOfDropDown(val2) }}
            </span>
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)<0">
            {{ val2 }}
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6atm89o/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `ng-repeat` will create its own scope, your value `selectItem` of `dropdownlist` can't be reached outside the `ng-repeat` block it currently belongs to.

the solution is that You have to bind a variable which should be defined in your controller to the `dropdownlist`, so that its value can be reached in the `ng-repeat` of `tr`. then you can show data based on what you have selected at column header by

```
val2[0][selectItem.selectItem]
```

refer example **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marrypen/h6atm89o/9/)**.

Comment: works very nice dynamically , thanks for ur hard/smart work .